# Format main OS hard drive with non-standard allocation unit size before restoring Ghost image

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, filesystems, formatting, norton-ghost

1. I want to try formatting my main internal hard drive with NTFS using an allocation unit size of 64 KB instead of the default 4KB.
2. Then I have a Windows 7 Ghost image that I will be restoring to the newly formatted drive.

*I was hoping to achieve slightly better performance with this setup.*

**What sequence of steps will allow me to format my main drive with a non-standard allocation unit size?  And will I keep the non-standard allocation unit size after restoring my Ghost image?**

*(I may want to use [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php) instead of Norton Ghost.  Would that be possible too?)*

Comment: Nothing, no attempts at this.. :(  I have an idea.  I'll try it and report back if it works.